# Schur functors are pairwise non isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-polynomials, functors, representation-of-algebras

In [Fulton-Harris](https://mat.uab.cat/%7Epitsch/ReadingSeminar/Fulton-Harris.pdf) Part I Weyl's construction there a characterization of some of the irreducible representation of $GL(V)$, with $V$ a finite complex vector space. In particular, Theorem $6.3$ point $(4)$ states that $S_{\lambda}V$ with $\lambda$ partition of $d$ are irreducible. For this it sufficient to know that Lemma $6.22$ can be applied.

I'd like to know whether I could infer that $S_{\lambda}V$ is not isomorphic to $S_{\mu}V$ when $\lambda \ne \mu$.
I have the sentence written on my notes taken during class after the statement $(3)$ ( which states that $\chi_{S_{\lambda}V}(g) = s_{\lambda}(x_1,\cdots,x_k)$, where $s_{\lambda}$ is the schur symmetric functions and $x_1,\cdots,x_k$ are the eigenvalues of $g \in GL(V)$).

What I don't get is how the characters could be enough since here we are talking about obejcts having a $B = Hom_{S_d}(V^{\otimes d},V^{\otimes d})$ module structure while, as far as I see completly invariance of characters could be used only for representations of (finite groups in particular) symmetric group $S_d$ (since a reason could be that $s_{\lambda}$ are the characters of the irreducible representions of $S_d$). There is any relation between being an $S_d$-representation and $B$ representation which could give what I'm looking for, i.e $S_{\lambda}V$ is not isomorphic to $S_{\mu}V$ when $\lambda \ne \mu$.

Any help of solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character can be defined for finite-dimensional representations of an arbitrary group $G$ (or more generally for finite-dimensional modules over an arbitrary algebra), and it's an invariant of that representation in this generality, so for an arbitrary group $G$, if two representations have different characters they cannot be isomorphic. This does not require the stronger result for finite groups that if two representations have the *same* character then they *are* isomorphic (which is generally false for infinite groups and for algebras); it is much easier and true in much more generality.

So yes, it suffices to know that the Schur functions are different.

Comment: And there is a standard method to prove that they are different seen as $B$-representations?

Comment: @jacopoburelli: like I said, it suffices to show that the Schur functions are different.